# How do I groupby nested lists?

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects each containing a list of strings, and I want to use group objects that contain the same value within their lists.
I'm trying something like this, but it puts them all in the same lists.

```
List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
Item Item1 = new Item();
Item1.Id = "1";
Item1.Names.AddRange(new List<string> { "A" });
Items.Add(Item1);

Item Item2 = new Item();
Item2.Id = "2";
Item2.Names.AddRange(new List<string> { "B" });
Items.Add(Item2);

Item Item3 = new Item();
Item3.Id = "3";
Item3.Names.AddRange(new List<string> { "A", "C" });
Items.Add(Item3);

List<List<Item>> GroupedItems = Items.GroupBy(u => u.Names.GroupBy(s => s)).Select(t => t.ToList()).ToList();
```

What I would like to have happen in this scenario is `GroupedItems` contains two lists, the first contains `Item1`and `Item3`, the second contains `Item2`.

Comment: Still not clear what are trying to accomplish. When you want to use LINQ `GroupBy` operation you should provide a `keySelector` function, that is a function which will generate key object for every item in your collection. Then all items having the same key object will be grouped together.

Comment: Suppose you have `item1.Names = { "A", "B" }`,  `item2.Names = { "A", "C" }`,  `item3.Names = { "B", "C" }`. What do you want to receive in such a case?

Comment: @IvanGritsenko I just want items with similar values in their lists to be grouped together. It doesn't matter if the same item shows up in more than one group. thanks.

Comment: So you want a separate group for every string value you encounter in all of the items, right? For your example you want the result to have 3 groups : `for "A": item1, item3`, `for "B": item2`, `for "C": item3`. Am I right?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Comment: actually not quite, but I can work with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<List<Item>> GroupedItems = Items
    // Select only distinct names that can occur
    .SelectMany(x => x.Names).Distinct()
    // For every unique name find items that have it in Names
    .Select(name => Items.Where(x => x.Names.Contains(name)).ToList())
    .ToList();
```